# Ubuntu 13.04 claims wrong password

Tags: 13.04, password, cinnamon

So I am trying to open my file manager as root, but when it asks for my password, it says it is incorrect. I am the ONLY user on this system, I am setup as Administrator (confirmed in the "details" dialog). It is the same password I use to install software, login, etc. It works for everything EXCEPT opening the file manager as root. I have tried it with nemo, nautilus, & Thunar...all give same result.

Comment: how you are trying to open as root, exact command?

Comment: I have tried right click select "open as root" as well as gksu nautilus (or other file managers) Also relevant may be that when I try to reset my password, everything I enter is either too weak or "not good enough". This happens even when I try a randomly generated password produced by the change password dialog.

Comment: Truthfully, I am about 10 seconds from going back to Manjaro. Dispite being a rolling release, I have not had anywhere near the problems Ubuntu has had. It is one error after another. This release is getting close to rivaling Windows in the number of problems it has!

Comment: by default `gksu` is removed from 13.04. have you installed it? [PSA: gksu is no longer installed by default](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6634)

Comment: almost same problem i am getting for other administrative things everything goes ok but on opening graphical bootup manager the same password it shows as wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,  I installed nemo file manager which has admin privileges and dont have a problem although you have to open nemo in a terminal "sudo nemo" enter your password,  you now have elevated admin privileges. By the way if I have nemo file manager open without admin privileges and right click open with admin privileges it doesnt work. I have to open nemo in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem got it working :
run the command gksu-properties and change the "Authentication mode" to "sudo" and close. Now do gksu bleachbit, or whatever GUI application you want to run as root, and type your password (the one you use for updating and installing)